# MBED + STM32F446RE: can't call function in RAM

Tags: stm32

If I try to put a method in the .data section using the below code, the microcontroller hangs when I try to call it. Is it a wrong way?

(When I check in the disassembly it appears indeed in the RAM)

```c
__attribute__((long_call, section(".data"))) void my_ram_method() {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: Are you putting it in RAM that is executable?

Comment: Does it hang even for an empty(ish) function, or only if there's some code in there?

Comment: Actually I apologize I forgot to update this question status, I am using MBED and I realized that RAM is flagged as not callable in the MPU by default

https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.4/apis/mpu-management.html